# Rails has_many association and ActiveRecord#clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many

shepherd `has_many` animals. I am trying to clone one of them:

```
dolly=shepherd.animals.build(sheep.clone)
```

I get error:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys!' for #<Sheep:0xb6ce154c>
```

why? what is another way to clone dolly so that she would be associated with a shepherd and have sheep's attributes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
dolly = shepherd.animals.build(sheep.clone.attributes)
```

`build` requires the argument to be a hash of attributes. Otherwise

```
dolly = shepherd.animals << sheep.clone
```

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord::Base constructors take a parameter hash. Passing an object doesn't quite do it. So you need to query the attributes hash of the object in question.

```
dolly=shepherd.animals.build(sheep.clone.attributes)
```

In fact the constructors ignore the id attribute, so you can get away with:

```
dolly=shepherd.animals.build(sheep.attributes)
```